# Passing Structures in C

Tags: c, pgm

I am working on a program that is supposed to handle a PGM image file of the form

```
P2
24 7
11
0  0   0   0   0   0  0   0  0  0  0   0   0  0   0   0   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
0  11  11  11  11  0  11  0  0  0  11  0   0  11  0   0   0  11  0  0  0  11  0  0
0  11  0   0   0   0  11  0  0  0  11  0   11  0  11  0   0  11  11 0  0  11  0  0
0  11  11  11  11  0  0  11  0  11  0  0   11  11 11  0   0  11  0  11 0  11  0  0
0  11  0   0   0   0  0  11  0  11  0  11  0  0   0   11  0  11  0  0  11 11  0  0
0  11  11  11  11  0  0  0  11  0   0  11  0  0   0   11  0  11  0  0  0  11  0  0
0  0   0   0   0   0  0  0  0   0   0  0   0  0   0   0   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
7  7   7   7   7   7  7  7  7   7   7  7   7  7   7   7   7  7  7  7  7  7  7  7
```

I have the following structure to hold the data and the init function

```
struct Image {
    int row, column;
    int maxValue;
    unsigned int data[MAXLINELENGTH];
}

 Image * Image_Init ()
{
     Image tmp_Image;
     tmp_Image.row = 0;
     tmp_Image.column = 0;
     int i;
     for (i = 0; i < MAXLINELENGTH; i++)
     {
        tmp_Image.data[i] = 0;
     }
     return &tmp_Image;
}
```

It gives me a warning saying that the function returns the address of a local variable. What I want to do is create basically an object Image, and pass that through. How would I go about doing this?

Thank You

EDIT===================================

I seem to be able to use

```
 Image * Image_Init ()
{
     Image *tmp_Image;
     tmp_Image->row = 0;
     tmp_Image->column = 0;
     int i;
     for (i = 0; i < MAXLINELENGTH; i++)
     {
        tmp_Image->data[i] = 0;
     }
     return tmp_Image;
}
```

Now I am having issues with the one where I need to read in the data from an array.
I'm using the same basic structure

```
Image * Image_Init_From_Array (unsigned int height, unsigned int width, unsigned int *data)
{
    Image *tmp_Image;
    tmp_Image->row = width;
    tmp_Image->column = height;
    tmp_Image->maxValue = 255;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < MAXLINELENGTH; i++)
    {
        tmp_Image->data[i] = data[i];
    }
    return tmp_Image;
}
```

This compiles fine, but results in a segmentation fault.

Comment: You can pass pointer to `tmp_Image` as an argument in `Image_Init` function.

Comment: For the edit part: tmp_Image is a wild pointer at that time, pointing anywhere and access to that memory will cause a SEGFAULT

Answer (score 1):

If you need to pass the struct by pointer, it will need to be allocated somewhere. You can allocate it statically or automatically and pass pointers to lower scopes (cannot pass pointer *higher* than its scope).

```
my_function() {
    Image tmp_image;
    Image_init(&tmp_image);
    //...
}
```

Or allocate it globally, and take an address:

```
Image tmp_image;

my_function() {
    Image_init(&tmp_image);
    //...
}
```

Or allocate it dynamically:

```
my_function() {
    Image *tmp_image;
    tmp_image = malloc(sizeof(Image));
    Image_init(tmp_image);  // this time it's already a pointer, so no '&'
    //...
}
```

If you allocate dynamically, you don't need to have all that extra space for small images. Instead, calculate the space you need before allocating. You may want to combine the functions of allocating and initializing, and make a constructor function to allocate and initialize in one step:

```
typedef struct {
    int row, column;
    int maxValue;
    unsigned int data[];  //C99 allows this empty array to do the "struct hack"
} Image;

Image *new_Image (int row, int column, int max) {
    Image *tmp = malloc(sizeof(Image) + row*column);
    if (tmp != NULL) {
        tmp->row = row;
        tmp->column = column;
        tmp->maxValue = max;
    }
    return tmp;
}
```

For ANSI C, you'll have to put a `1` for the size of the data array, and subtract `1` from the size calculation. You could also declare the data field as a pointer and either allocate it separately, or like here `sizeof(Image) + row*columns` -- as one block -- but you'd need to set the pointer, too.

Answer (score 1):

Just pass in a pointer to image:

```
Image * Image_Init (Image * i)
```

Then fill that one out. You can then either return the pointer or use the variable the passed pointer in the calling function points to:

Basically:

```
  Image * Image_Init (Image *tmp_Image)
 {

      tmp_Image->row = 0;
      tmp_Image->column = 0;
      int i;
      for (i = 0; i < MAXLINELENGTH; i++)
      {
         tmp_Image->data[i] = 0;
      }
      return tmp_Image;
 }

 void caller()
 {
     Image img;

     Image_Init(&img);

     // work with img here
  }
```

For the edit part: tmp_Image is a wild pointer at that time, pointing anywhere and access to that memory will cause a SEGFAULT. Especially in this function where you want to manipulate an existing 'object', you will need to pass in the struct as a pointer:

```
Image * Image_Init_From_Array (Image * image, unsigned int height, unsigned int width, unsigned int *data)
{
...
}
```

Comment: Doing `Image img = {0};` seems to be more easy.

Comment: True, but I guess this was not the assignment ;)

Comment: We are confined to using Image * Image_Init_From_Array (unsigned int height, unsigned int width, unsigned int *data) and Image *Image_Init (). We are not really allowed to add in pointers to external objects. From the runme program we have Image *i1; i1 = Image_Init_From_Array(10, 20, hi);

Answer (score 1):

Your edited function allocates memory for a pointer to `Image`, but not for an `Image` variable.

Your comment to LostBoy's answer says that you have to conform to a given signature:

```
Image *i1; 
i1 = Image_Init_From_Array(10, 20, hi);
```

This implies that `Image_Init_From_Array()` must allocate the memory by itself. You cannot just create an `Image` variable in the function, since the memory for that variable would be freed again at exiting the function.

This situation is a typical use for `malloc()`.

- Allocate memory for an `Image` object in the `Image_Init_From_Array()` function
- return a pointer to the newly created object
- pass that pointer to other functions that need the object
- write a `Image_delete(Image *)` function, where you free the memory earlier allocated by `malloc()`. If you do not do that, you'd have a memory leak.